# postfix/postdrop Issue with Solaris 10 (sparc) - permissions

Tags: permissions, postfix, solaris, setgid

I am trying to get postfix (installed from blastwave) working on a Solaris 10 server, but only root is allowed to send mail.  The problem appears to be permission related with postdrop.

```
postdrop: warning: mail_queue_enter: create file maildrop/905318.27416: Permission denied
```

I've checked that /var/opt/csw/spool/postfix/maildrop and /var/opt/csw/spool/postfix/public are both in the 'postdrop' group.  main.cf contains setgid_group = postdrop.

ppriv on postdrop as non-root user reports:

```
postdrop[27336]: missing privilege "file_dac_write" (euid = 103, syscall = 5) needed at ufs_iaccess+0x110
```

I'm at a loss as to what to do next.  I'm don't have much experience with Solaris; I use Linux daily.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Solaris uses [RBAC](http://www.c0t0d0s0.org/archives/4077-Less-known-Solaris-features-RBAC-and-Privileges.html) (Role Based Access Control) which is similar to SELinux and AppArmor on Linux.  Although you have already solved this problem, [knowing this](http://blogs.oracle.com/jayd/entry/solaris_tip_of_the_week7) may help you in the future if you choose to stick with Solaris.

Comment: Thanks, @Ladadadada.  The links you provided were quite enlightening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried postfix from OpenCSW?  There's a newer version available (2.8.6 instead of 2.7.1), and this issue might have been addressed there.

Answer (score 1):

The user with the id 103 (see your /etc/passwd for correspondig user) has not the right to write to the Postfix queue directory. You get the queue directory path with the command `postconf queue_directory`.

Comment: I understand that, but it isn't obvious as to why.  In this case, the queue_directory is /var/opt/csw/spool/postfix, which is owned by root but is in the group postdrop.  Standard configuration according to all the postfix documentation I've seen.